# swiftのテーブルビューにおけるセル内のテキストの表示に関して

Tags: swift, uitableview

テーブルビューのセルにテキストを表示する時は例えば

let cell = UITableViewCell()
cell.textLabel.text = "あああ"

と書くと思いますが、
この時にcellはUITableViewCellクラスのインスタンスで、
textLabelはそのプロパティであることは分かりますが、
textはどういう位置付けなのでしょうか。

textLabel.textと書かれるということは
textLabel内のプロパティのように思いますが、
textLabel自体がUITableViewCellクラスのプロパティであり、
プロパティ内のプロパティとはどういう状態でしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

不要な部分をざっくり省略すると、こう言うことです。

```
class UITableViewCell: ... {
   var textLabel: UILabel?

   //...
}

class UILabel: ... {
   var text: String?

   //...
}
```

`UITableViewCell`には`textLabel`というプロパティがあり、そのデータ型である`UILabel`(実際は`UILabel?`ですが)には、`text`というプロパティがあります。

プロパティ内のプロパティ、こんな風に何重にも重なることはあります。

Comment: 回答して頂きありがとうございました。